# Convert stopwatch "hh:mm:ss:ms" to store in database

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, converters, stopwatch

I'm trying to save timings of variable length in my database. The longest could include hours, shorter ones only minutes. The shorter strings will only read "mm:ss.ms" or ":ss.ms", so the overall length will be shorter.

I've tried `DateTime`, but it requires Year,month, and day. I tried to set the date to 0000-00-00, which did not work.

I tried hard-coding everything, but was hoping there is a more elegant solution. This is how far I got:

```
// for shorter string of type ":mm.ms"
 if (myString.length >= 3) AND (myString.length <= 4) {
      if (myString.contains(':')) {
        myString.substring(1); //remove initial semicolon
      }
      int _seconds = int.parse(myString.substring(0,1));
      int _milliseconds = int.parse(myString.substring(3,3));
 }
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use a `Duration`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your problem right, this might be a solution for you:

```
  String test = ":23.24";
  String minutes = test.split(":")[0];
  String seconds = test.split(":")[1].split(".")[0];
  String milliseconds = test.split(":")[1].split(".")[1];

  Duration duration = Duration(
      minutes: int.tryParse(minutes) ?? 0,
      seconds: int.tryParse(seconds) ?? 0,
      milliseconds: int.tryParse(milliseconds) ?? 0);
  print(duration.inMilliseconds);
```

Edit: I found an other way, that also allows hours and it's more robust:

```
int parseTimeString(String string, {int currentLayer = 0}) {
  if ((string?.length ?? 0) == 0) return 0;
  String splitString = currentLayer == 0 ? "." : ":";
  int parsed =
      int.tryParse(string.substring(string.lastIndexOf(splitString) + 1)) ?? 0;
  Duration duration;
  switch (currentLayer) {
    case 0:
      duration = Duration(milliseconds: parsed);
      break;
    case 1:
      duration = Duration(seconds: parsed);
      break;
    case 2:
      duration = Duration(minutes: parsed);
      break;
    case 3:
      duration = Duration(hours: parsed);
      break;
  }
  return duration.inMilliseconds +
      parseTimeString(
          string.substring(
              0,
              string.lastIndexOf(splitString) == -1
                  ? 0
                  : string.lastIndexOf(splitString)),
          currentLayer: currentLayer + 1);
}
```

Edit2: I think this should work for you.

```
int parseTimeString(String string, {int currentLayer = 0}) {
  if ((string?.length ?? 0) == 0) return 0;
  String splitString = currentLayer == 0 ? "." : ":";
  String substring = string.substring(string.lastIndexOf(splitString) + 1);
  if(currentLayer == 0){
    while(substring.length<3){
      substring += "0";
    }
  }
  int parsed =
      int.tryParse(substring) ?? 0;
  Duration duration;
  switch (currentLayer) {
    case 0:
      duration = Duration(milliseconds: parsed);
      break;
    case 1:
      duration = Duration(seconds: parsed);
      break;
    case 2:
      duration = Duration(minutes: parsed);
      break;
    case 3:
      duration = Duration(hours: parsed);
      break;
  }
  return duration.inMilliseconds +
      parseTimeString(
          string.substring(
              0,
              string.lastIndexOf(splitString) == -1
                  ? 0
                  : string.lastIndexOf(splitString)),
          currentLayer: currentLayer + 1);
}

String timeToString(int millis){
  Duration duration = Duration(milliseconds: millis);
  String result = duration.toString();
  while(result.substring(result.length-1)=="0"){
    result = result.substring(0,result.length-1);
  }
  if(result.substring(result.length-1)==".")
    result += "0";
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I forgot the hours in this code. But adding them should be easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I really like the approach! I noticed 2 strange things though: For a time of 2:45.1, I get 165001 milliseconds. Using DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch to convert it back, I get '1970-01-01 01:02:45.001' .
I suppose '1970-01-01 01:00:00' is basically '0' for DateTime, but how would I convert this back from my Database to display in my app? The second thing is that I couldn't fix the milliseconds being 1/100 of the original.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great.
It took me a bit to figure out, but to convert milliseconds to display the time I used:

 ```
format(Duration d) => d.toString().substring(0, 9);

Duration newTime = new Duration(milliseconds: (parseTimeString(myString)));
print(format(newTime));
 ```